# Google Script POST to Basecamp Classic API

Tags: javascript, post, google-apps-script, basecamp

After a little help in regards to posting a new message to the Basecamp API using Google Script.

I have created a function, pasted below but when running this through the debugger I get a 422 response from Basecamp saying the `<title>` attribute is empty which it isn't

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <errors> <error>Title can't be blank</error> </errors>
```

I have tried the same POST via the 'Advanced Rest Client' in Chrome and the post is successful.

```
function postBasecampApi(endpoint, payload) {

  var xml = ""+
    '<request>'+
      '<post>'+
        '<category-id>123890662</category-id>'+
          '<title>sting</title>'+
            '<body>testing</body>'+
              '</post>'+
                '<notify>test notify</notify>'+
                  '</request>';

  var url = basecampCompleteUrl + '/projects/12029591/posts.xml';  

  var headers = {
    Authorization : 'Basic ' +  Utilities.base64Encode(user + ':' + password)
  }
  var opt = {
    'method': 'POST',
    'payload': xml,
    'headers' : headers
  };

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, opt);

  return Xml.parse(response.getContentText(), false);
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem, the fetch Content-Type default is not 'application/xml'. I added the following to the opt object and everything worked fine

```
var opt = {
  'contentType': 'application/xml',
  'method': 'POST',
  'payload': xml,
  'headers' : headers
};
```

It is worth nothing adding `Content-Type` to the headers does not work